# Xcode doesn't export all UILabels for localization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization

I'm using interface builder and its new (xcode 6) localization. Everything is working fine, but I found out, that few UILabels isn't exported. After a while I realized, that all skipped UILabels has NEWLINE in text(via control+enter).

Is there any workaround? Or is this happening only to me (I'm using xCode 6.2)

Answer (score 0):

When I add EOL with shortcut `control+Q+enter`, then UILabel is normally added to localization export.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set text of labels with key value from Localizable.strings.
New line should be done *"\n"* this should work.